# How to advance time in Dragon Age Inquisition tac cam for PC?

Tags: controllers, dragon-age-inquisition, keyboard

I looked into many guides and videos about the tactical camera in dragon age inquisition. Often the "advance time" function is mentioned, and in videos where a game pad controller is used, there is a specific button to advance time. How do I do it with keyboard and mouse? I could not find anything on that...

Comment: Do you mean unpause?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to advance time with a keyboard and mouse setup. It is possible on consoles and on PC with a controller only.

I initially thought that the arrows on either side on the hourglass were for time control, but either they aren't or it hasn't been implemented yet/correctly.

Perhaps a future patch will see the introduction of time control in tactical view on keyboard and mouse, but it does not exist at the moment.

Comment: The arrows are for different fields of view, to switch between tactical mode and action mode without using the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I believe, though I tend to ignore the tactical setup, that you can do so via the Ctrl key. It will toggle between paused and live. Or you can click on the icon (an hourglass inside an eye) in the center of the toolbar.

Comment: This is pause/unpause, which I regularly use. However on the screenshot in the manual there is the "advance time" option, which was at least in some description explained as kind of a slow motion. However, I'm not sure whether I am correct here. Do you play on a console or pc?

Comment: I use both, but I tend to ignore the tac cam. Ill look at the manual soon and try to see what they're referencing.